# JSON parser for Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm starting with iOs. I'd like to know if there is a built-in JSON parser and , if not, what is the best alternative for mapping JSON string into Cocoa objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5 only, then there is the built-in NSJSONSerialization class that will do the job nicely. If you need it to work in older versions of iOS, then something like SBJSON works well for me

Answer (score 3):

There is a built in JSON parser (NSJSONSerialization) in iOS 5 and above.

If you want to target earlier versions of iOS, there are many third party ones such as [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

**JSONKit**

JSONKit is dual licensed under either the terms of the BSD License, or alternatively under the terms of the Apache License, Version 2.0.
 Copyright © 2011, John Engelhart.

**A Very High Performance Objective-C JSON Library**

UPDATE: (2011/12/18) The benchmarks below were performed before Apples NSJSONSerialization was available (as of Mac OS X 10.7 and iOS 5). The obvious question is: Which is faster, NSJSONSerialization or JSONKit? According to this site, JSONKit is faster than NSJSONSerialization. Some quick "back of the envelope" calculations using the numbers reported, JSONKit appears to be approximately 25% to 40% faster than NSJSONSerialization, which is pretty significant.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) , it is not a built-in JSON parser, but I recommand it, you can try it.