# Swift: Parsing JSON file

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, swifty-json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54feffe1412807551c90eaa2"} , "loc" : [ 35.09 , 12.01]},
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54ff0b62412807551c90eaa4"} , "loc" : [ 43.98 , 12.34]}
```

How can I parse this JSON file in Swift? I need the values in loc.

Comment: You could've easily found this by googling "xcode json to nsdictionary"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode Parse Json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801506/xcode-parse-json)

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem, that I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I send a http request to my server. Like this

```
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            var datastring:String = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
//          println(datastring)

            if (data != nil) {
                var json=NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &self.err) as NSDictionary
                println(json)

                if (error != nil) {
                    println(self.err?.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                  //do something here with json
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

and get this json file:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54feffe1412807551c90eaa2"} , "loc" : [ 35.09 , 12.01]},
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54ff0b62412807551c90eaa4"} , "loc" : [ 43.98 , 12.34]}
```

If I have only one file it works. But with two files I get the fatal error.

Comment: it seems that my json file is not a valid json.

Comment: Yes, Format is wrong. Please check on online validator tool. And For JSON you have pasted just put square braces on start and end.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
func ParseJSONData(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    if let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary { return dict }

    println("Failed to parse")
    return nil
}

// *********************

if let info = ParseJSONData(jsonstring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false))
```

Comment: is jsonstring NSData?

Comment: I dont know what you will be using but for this example jsonstring is of course a String.

Comment: Please give me a purpose for the downvote, this is clearly what OP is asking for...

Comment: I didnt say it was you.